# How to get the web element by using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, return-value, getattribute

I want to get the items within the td statements. How can I do this?
I tried it with value but it always returns null.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(" j_id55:searchresults "))
String elementval = element.getAttribute("value")
System.out.println("elementval:" +elementval)
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code you actually tried?

Answer (score 0):

try with .getText() instead of .getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

you are using incomplete id.

You are using `j_id55:searchresults`

while I think you are looking for `j_id55:searchresults:0:j_id130`

Above id will give you data as `gi00081787`

Now use `.getText()`

You code should be like below:-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("j_id55:searchresults:0:j_id130"));
String elementval = element.getText();
System.out.println("elementval:" +elementval);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

by typing id `j_id55:searchresults` you get table as webElement you need to be more specific what you want to get from it

for your example :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='j_id55:searchresults']//tbody/tr/td[3]"));
String elementval = element.getText();
System.out.println("elementval:" +elementval)
```

**For the future use:**

- Rows in the table is dynamic so the best way handle table is to put the tr/td into List

For example list of table tr in your case is:

```
List<WebElement> trCollection = driver.findElement(By.id("j_id55:searchresults")).findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```